# how would i make a dictionary from two lists in ironpython 2.7

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ironpython

I have two lists:

```
names = ["adrien", "lisa", "kevin"]
rating = [2, 5, 4]
```

I am trying to make them into a dictionary in IronPython2.7

```
list_tuples = zip(names, rating )
professions_dict = dict([(x,y) for x,y in enumerate(list_tuples)])
```

I am getting an error that says that `int` does not contain a definition for a key

[image]

Comment: What is the expected output? `{'adrien': 2, 'lisa': 5, 'kevin': 4}`? In that case `dict(zip(names, rating))` is enough. Provided `lisa` is actually string and not a list, that is.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes i want a dictionary but keep getting an error back saying that 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Key

Comment: why are you ``enumerate``'ing the list? your ``x`` in the case is going to be the index of the tuple (I.E. it will be ``0, 1, 2, 3, 4...``) and ``y`` will be the actual tuple at the index. Try just doing what @MartijnPieters suggested.

Comment: @konrad: when you get errors, please *include the full traceback* of your error. And include the expected output in your question, rather than have us guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's all my error says. I am sorry about not making it clear what i expected to be the output. You guessed it right. I wanted a dictionary.

Comment: @konrad: a dictionary *with what **contents***? You are saying you are getting an error, include the full error message.

Comment: In CPython, your code produces this dictionary `{0: ('adrien', 2), 1: ('lisa', 5), 2: ('kevin', 4)}` -- so your error message (which doesn't match what you say you got in your question) makes little sense. Doesn't the `IronPythonEvaluator` indicate the line number with the problem? It may be some other Python code you have or you're not putting the proper data into the dictionary.

Comment: can not reproduce using 2.7.5b2, my result matches what martineau posted

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ["adrien", "lisa", "kevin"]
rating = [2, 5, 4]

mydict = {key:value for key,value in zip(names,rating)}
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.